# Time complexity of LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, logistic-regression

Is it possible to assess the time complexity of training logistic regression for 2 classes using LBFGS optimizer? Is there a general understending how fast it converges? Let's say, I know that it takes 30 min for 5 mln rows. How much it would take for 50 mln rows?

Comment: This is very hard to answer and some *general* theoretical answer won't be that useful when applied to this specific task imho. It will be quite dependen on your data and i recommend doing some epirical analysis: calc 1m, 5m, 10m and see yourself (probably a good idea to do multiple runs per size with different data/subsets).

Comment: it also depends highly on your implementation, maybe you can add some code which would make it much easier to compute the overall complexity